# Magento - Save Category results in: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: magento, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to create and save a category in the admin system using Magento CE-1.9.0.0

When i go to Add Sub Category the page loads, i can fill out the information but then when i press Save it gets stuck on the please wait popup no matter where i am placing the category or what information I enter.

Using firefox and firebug i can see this output:

```
"NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable -     
http://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/save/key/xxxx/store/0/parent/115/?isAjax=true"
```

and when i look further into the ajax response i can see:

```
<pre>SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation: 
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`table`.`catalog_category_entity_varchar`, 
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) O)
```

What does this mean? I have removed/disabled all known plugins/extensions with the same problem.

I have looked at my database and `catalog_category_entity_varchar` table is still there and everything looks ok in there

I can edit,delete,move all my existing categories ok.

Also i can add a category programetically with php as below:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setName($name);
$category->setIsActive(1);   
$category->setIsAnchor(0);
$category->setIncludeInMenu(0);
$category->save();
```

which works fine, it is just in admin that this problem occurs

Comment: have you reindexed recently?  does it complete?

Comment: Re indexes several times and it completed both times.